# Magento 2.2.2 ERROR Unable to serialize value

Tags: magento2

After clean installation of Magento 2 and Template I got these error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to serialize value.

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to serialize value.
#0 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/PageCache/Kernel.php(153): Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->serialize(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(96): Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Kernel->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#2 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->afterRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#4 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#9 {main}
```

Comment: try to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: Hi, please take a look into https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202448/magento-2-2-1-unable-to-serialize-value