# Magento 2 : Item order details not showing after migration for old records

Tags: magento2, sales-order, migration, order-details

I have migrate magento1 to magento 2.2.5, after migration in old order records item details are not showing in backend.

In database all details are available but still item not showing in backend only Product name and price are displayed.

Can anyone have fix of this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was previously reported to the git several times ago.

Check it here.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12411

One more at [Magento 2.2.1 Unable to serialize value](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202448/magento-2-2-1-unable-to-serialize-value)

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/203060/49826

Very well explained.