# ERROR coming while adding product through admin panel

Tags: magento2, product

**After clicking on the add product, an error occurred during application run.**

Please see the below exception log for details:

```
Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Magento2_3/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:26)"} []
```

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202448/magento-2-2-1-unable-to-serialize-value

Comment: Not working!!!!